# Why does turning on encrypted DNS unblock some geo locked websites?

Tags: dns, isp, cloudflare

When I turn on Warp provided by Cloudflare or use 1.1.1.1, it unlocks some of the websites which are geo locked. How does it unblock the websites which are blocked by ISP?

Comment: Have you read Warps' docs?

Comment: Yeah, but I did not Cleary understand how it is unblocking the website.

Comment: 1.1.1.1 encrypts your DNS. Warp does a lot more.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=how+does+warp+unblock+a+website

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time, it's not the ISP that is blocking the request, but the site itself. They usually have a list of countries that must not access it, and if your IP is in that table, you are blocked.

Other sites use DNS to direct you to another server with an error message, or a non-existing address (or an address without a server to answer). As they own the DNS server answering queues for their domain, it's cheap and easy to return a different address depending on the IP address of the requester.

Cloudflare Warp can help with the second case by doing the DNS request in your behalf. If their server are on an IP range of an unblocked country, the DNS server will give them the proper IP address for their server, and your computer connect there.

Warp can work as a VPN too, and that will help with the first case: their servers will do the DNS request and the connection in your behalf, so your IP will not be seen by the remote server.

Comment: "most of the time"? You can't really say that. It really depends on your location. And if a really bad site exists that an ISP would want blocked, they won't comply with requests to block certain countries.

Comment: Yeah, maybe but in my case my ISP was blocking the access to the site. I think encrypted DNS requests doesn't allow them to see my requests and I was able to access the blocked websites.

Comment: [This paper](https://ensa.fi/papers/403forbidden_imc18.pdf) shows CDN-level geoblocking. When Cloudflare itself is blocking your entire country from accessing certain sites, that affects way more people than any ISP inside the country could.

Comment: [This study](https://censoredplanet.org/censoredplanet) shows increase on DNS-level censorship detection on their studies affecting entire countries.

Comment: [This USENIX presentation](https://www.usenix.org/system/files/conference/usenixsecurity18/sec18-vandersloot.pdf) shows a few discoveries on country-level censorship by governments.

Answer (score 0):

If the ISP blocks websites based on DNS queries, then Warp's 1.1.1.1 encrypted DNS service means that the ISP can't see the DNS queries to block your request.

If you are using ​​1.1.1.1 with WARP or WARP via Local Proxy, then you are using a VPN/encrypted proxy to the Cloudflare edge, meaning that the ISP can't see the traffic to block it.

source: https://developers.cloudflare.com/warp-client/warp-modes/